# Div fixation with his mother

Tags: css

I use this CSS to display a fixed block on the left side of my web page. It is a red box with the words SPECIAL EVENT in white, provided by an image.

```
.special_event{
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 52px;
    height: 29px;
    background:url(../images/special_icon.png);
    left:10.5%;
}
```

[image: in 1200 pixel]

But when the screen resolution is larger than 1200 pixels, the div moves away from the main content.

[image: in 1920 pixel]

I would like the `special_event` div to remain immediately adjacent to the main content regardless of the screen resolution, as seen in the first picture. What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Question title of the day.

Comment: Please don't edit this question title!..

Comment: What about positioning the `special_event` relative to its container, with `position: absolute`?

Comment: `position:absolute` will work with a negative offset. But the fix on scrolling property will be lost.

Comment: @dfsq Oh no, the question title is too good to mess with. But I tried to take care of the rest of it.

Comment: What's your desired effect?

Comment: @user3243573 : add css for main container too.

Comment: @Leo That is explained at the end of the post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

[position fixed is relative to any position that is not static, thus content & fixed element is always in center and relative to its parent](http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/su4sqge6/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="content_wrapper" class="border">
    <div id="special_event" class="border"></div>
    <div id="main_content" class="border">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.border {
 border:1px solid red;   
}
#content_wrapper {
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
}
#special_event {
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 52px;
    height: 29px;
    top:0;
    margin-left:-52px;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `.special_event` element inside your main content, let'say `#main-content` and apply this CSS:

```
#main-content {
    position:relative;
    ....
}

.special_event {
    position:absolute;
    width:52px;
    left: -52px;
    ...
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var fixedTop = 100; // set to whatever you want
    $('.special-event').css({'top':fixedTop + 'px'});
});
```

Comment: The div will not remain fixed when scrolling in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:fixed` with float.

Use `float:right` for the special event div and the main container on the right. Then set `position:fixed`  for `.special_event`. Also set appropriate value of `right` attribute for `.special_event` so that it touches the left border of main container.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery to align the special event dom with the main content. WIth jquery you can get the offset.top of the main content, and as per that you can set the top of your special_event dom.

```
            // + you main content top
            function setTop(){

            var offset = $('main_content_selector').offset();

            var event_special_top = offset.top + 100; // here you can alter the 100 as per your need, it is used to center the special event dom relative to main content

            $('.special_event').css('top', event_special_top);

            }

            setTop();

            // event you can use the setTop with browser resize
```

Comment: Can't this be done in CSS? Pulling out jQuery seems like trying to swat a fly with an elephant gun. And, the problem doesn't appear to be vertical alignment anyway.